# How to correctly read an image file?

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, filestream

I tried using `FileStream` to read the image file and it succeeded reading it, but it outputs this error message

> "Parameter is not valid".

```
public Bitmap streamimage(string Fname)
{
    Bitmap bm;
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(Fname, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        bm = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(stream);
        stream.Close();
        return bm;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know about [this Bitmap constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cbhe98f.aspx)? You could try removing that `stream.Close()`, it will be closed automatically since it's wrapped in a `using`.

Comment: noted...can i know what cause "parameter is not valid"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
Image I = Image.FromFile("FilePath");
```

And use that image

```
Bitmap bm= new Bitmap(I);
```

Or

```
Bitmap bm= new Bitmap("FilePath");
```

And you can edit your code like this

```
public Bitmap streamimage(string Fname)
{
    Bitmap bm;
    FileStream stream = new FileStream(Fname, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    bm = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(stream);
    return bm;
}
```

Comment: Option 1 is ideal (+1), it takes care of all internals.

Answer (score 1):

When opening from a stream, the stream must remain open.

I would suggest that you use the contructor of the Bitmap that takes the file path as a parameter.

```
return new Bitmap(Fname);
```

Comment: Ah yes, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x.aspx) is the MSDN quote: "You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Image."